# How to use mysql query in forloop with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I want to update database in for loop with mysql query.

```
 for(let i=0;i<userarray.length;i++){
console.log(i);
     var sql = "update user set user_status=1 where id=" + userarray[i].id;
    con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;     
 console.log("Number of row update: " + result.affectedRows);


                });
     }
and the output is:
1
2
3
4
Number of row update:1
Number of row update:0
Number of row update:0
Number of row update:0
```

Here only one time database is updating.I found async/await is solution but i dont know how to use it.

Comment: Looping through each user id and executing one query per user id is highly ineffidient. Construct a single query instead and execute that single query one time. Something like `update user set user_status=1 where id in (userarray[0], userarray[1]...)`

Comment: Which library are you using for the database connection ?

Comment: mysql library ..

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) library you should use the parameter to insert the ids

```
const userarray = [{id:0}, {id:2}, {id:5}];
const idsList = [userarray .map(user => user.id)];
const sql = "UPDATE user SET user_status = 1 WHERE id IN (?)";

con.query(sql, idsList, (err, result) => {
  if(err) throw err; 
  console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `IN` operator within the SQL query

```js
let sql = 'update user set user_status = 1 where id IN (';
const userarray = [
  {
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
  },
];
for(let i = 0; i < userarray.length; i++) {
  const split = i === 0 ? '' : ',';
  sql += `${split}${userarray[i].id}`;
}
sql += ')';
console.log(sql)
```